# Is there an OSX terminal command (el capitan) to disable / hide panes in System Preferences?

Tags: macos, terminal, terminal.app, system-preferences

been Googling for the better part of an hour now and not too familiar with OSX ways of doing things via command line. If anyone has a great resource site for OSX system commands / switches that would be awesome. But I've found this for my specific issue:

https://themacwrangler.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/disabling-system-preference-panes-the-hardwrong-way/

Which seems a bit unreliable as it's not very straightforward in reversing. Disabling a pane is ideal but hiding is also fine. There's a way to do it via the view option (when in system preferences), clicking Customize, and unchecking hides what you want to hide. Is there a way to do this via terminal? Better yet, is there a way to just disable one of them? Thanks everyone!

Comment: That article you found seems like a fine solution. The only reason the author calls it hard/wrong is because editing plist files from a shell script is hard/wrong, similar to how [you can't edit HTML from regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Lots of shell scripters are used to using sed regexes to edit plain text config files, and get nervous when they have to call a tool like PlistBuddy to walk the data structures of a more complex config file format like Plists. But using PlistBuddy here is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can use AppleScript for manipulating the *System Preferences*, but you may find that no less complex.  Here are a few pages which give information on that approach:

- [Change System Preferences by script](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157370/applescriptsystempreferences.html)
- [Scriptable System Preferences](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/features/system-prefs.html)
- [Scripting System Preferences](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=24773)
- [Use AppleScript to change System Preferences without being visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16711861/use-applescript-to-change-system-preferences-without-being-visible)

Answer (score -1):

This is super simple from the UI if you want to do it to a single computer.

1. Launch System Preferences. From the main window, **`click and hold`** the grid icon in the window's title bar (*it's the button to the right of the back/forth buttons*)
2. A list of all Sys Pref items will appear. At the bottom of this list, there should be a `Customize...` option. Select this.
3. You should now see all of your System Preference icons with check marks to the bottom right of each item. Uncheck the items you wish to hide then click **`Done`** from the top of the window.
   [image: SysPref with selectable icons]
   If you want to do this on a larger scale, e.g. sys admin style, you'll need to google "System Preference profiles El Capitan". There's a lot of info and you can control many more aspects of the OS. Here's *[Apple's official mention](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH22006)* FWIW.

Comment: OP already mentioned the GUI method in their question.